# Building flutter ios app on macos dual booting on windows pc

Tags: ios, flutter, windows, macos, dart

I have searched to check if it's possible to build an ios app on a macOS that has been dual booted on a windows pc but haven't found a reliable answer to this question.

So please help me out. I want to dual boot macOS Ventura or atleast from Monterey and above on my windows pc (with Intel iris xe graphics 16gb ram and nvme ssd).

Will i be able to fully build the ios app without any restriction and get all available features i need or will there be an issue when creating the flutter app?

Thank you for your help

PS: i know this isn't a code problem but i really your your help in it

Comment: from my understanding i dont think so, since the simulators care about the apple hardware as well. But if you have a physical iphone, than you might be able to get around that.